# In Access 2003 Report, how to hide some detail rows?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm working up an MS Access report.  This report is grouped and has a details section.  But some of these details rows don't need to be shown.  How do I hide the details sections if, for example, "[fieldx] = 'foo'"?

(In Crystal Reports, there's a place where you can write custom criteria to suppress these kinds of things.  I can't find an equivalent functionality here in Access).

Comment: It's bad form to delete your question after you've received a correct answer.  Suggest you don't do that again.  Otherwise what incentive is there for anyone to answer your questions?

Comment: (FYI, If your name isn't HansUp, then this is in reference to an unrelated question)  Ooh, you tracked me down! Actually, your answer wasn't completely correct, although it was close.  I ended up figuring out the rest of it myself, but i wasn't in the mood to detail the complete answer.  But you do have a point.  I will think twice before deleting an answered question.

Comment: I already tried to undelete it, but I couldn't find it. Maybe self-deleted questions are hidden from everyone, including the OP.

Comment: In other news, I'm still looking for an answer to this question. Anyone? I already got around it by building a second table in the datasource, but I'm still hoping for a simple solution.

Comment: I like to show a little friendly personality sometimes.  SO doesn't have to be completely deadpan serious.  So does this mean it's not possible to hide detail rows?

Comment: If you're opening the report with DoCmd.OpenReport, you can provide the WhereCondition argument to eliminate the records you don't want displayed. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

As David suggested, you could pass WHERE condition to the report:

```
Function OpenReport(filterValue As String)

DoCmd.Close acReport, "ReportName"
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewReport, "", "[SomeFieldName]<>'" & filterValue & "'", acNormal

End Function
```